Angular project increases memory usage after every refresh
I have a problem in my Angular website and I am not sure what is the cause. Every time I refresh the page the memory usage increases by 100-150 mb of ram. I have already tried most of the recommended solutions for angular projects like:

Using unsubscribeand takeUntil()
Calling ngOnDestroy() on window.beforeunload
Removed eventListeners in ngOnDestroy()
Disabled cache

The problem still persists. I also tried in many browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari etc and the same happens there. One intresting note is that when I ran manualy the garbage collector through the Chrome Developer tools the memory of the application goes back to normal, but of cource when I start refreshing again it goes back up. Here is a screenshot of the performance monitor when I repeatedly refresh:

As you can see the JS heap size is constantly increasing after each refresh. I noticed that the same thing happes for pretty much every website but the memory goes back to normal after 1-2 seconds, probably that's the time the garbage collector runs.
My question is why does the garbage collector or whatever is that was supposed to return the memory back to normal doesn't work and my web app has constantly increasing memory after each refresh?

looks like number of DOM nodes is correlating.   Include some code.  Seems like an array keeps getting larger and there's a for loop adding nodes based on it.

Thanks for your answer @browsermator. This project is quite big so I am not sure which part of the code I should include. I thought that on each refresh the Javascript arrays where being deleted. Is there any way to check which arrays are currently in memory?

debugging...  if you are refreshing a single page, it shouldn't be too difficult to track down.   I think the only difference between refresh and basic navigations is properties declared and/or initialized.  Constructor/oninit/etc... should always be hit.  I've never really delved into the browser's garbage collection, so not real sure what happens there.  I suppose it needs to know that there are no longer any references to the item to collect it.  (whether that's a node, a property/method, etc..)  It may also schedule collection for a later time.  (when it truly needs more memory)

considering that, there may not be an issue at all.  You may need to monitor for a longer amount of time to see when the browser's garbage collection kicks in.

I made some more testing on empty angular projects in different angular version and the same problem occurs. I also let my app run for some more time and indeed the garbage collector run and the memory goes down. The problem is that in empty projects the garbage collector runs pretty fast and in my app it doesn't.

the GC logic is probably pretty complicated and would vary by browser.  It may run collection at times when the browser isn't doing much... it may also do it when it is doing a lot but there's a certain threshold met (say 90% of available memory used).  We don't have control over the browser's GC from our code, but in the browser's dev tools I believe you can trigger it manually.  Using that, you could test for things like endlessly growing arrays or memory leaks.
